# Linux: aliases when using `screen`

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, alias

I'm using `screen`, and I have several aliases in my `~/.bash_profile`, for example `python=python-2.6`. But for some reasons these aliases don't work when I work in `screen`. How can I make them work?

Comment: I want to open multiple new windows in screen and execute my alias in each of those, ie, "screen -t window1 my_alias". Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bash_profile` gets run when in a login shell.  You'll probably want to put your aliases in the `.bashrc` file.  Or you could just execute your `.bash_profile` each time that you start up a shell in `screen`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` option to bash in your `.screenrc` to start your screen session's bash shells as login shells:

```
screen bash -l
```

Comment: Using this method you would have to type "exit" twice - once to exit the additional bash session, and then second time to exit screen.

Comment: The same applies to the original question. The example I showed here was for a `.screenrc` file to open the shell as a login shell.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your ~/.screenrc file:

```
shell -/bin/bash
```

The initial dash executes the shell with login option

Answer (score 0):

If you run `exec bash` after you start up screen, they will work