# How do execute a bash alias in a new screen window?

Tags: linux, bash

In my .screenrc, I have several lines similar to the following:

```
screen -t qf1 bash
```

So for that window, I am currently executing bash. Instead, I would like to execute the following alias "qf" which is a bash alias that executes lynx for a certain URL.

However, I get the following error:

```
"Cannot exec 'qf': No such file or directory"
```

I know it probably has something to do with the path, but providing:

```
screen -t qf1 lynx www.google.com
```

Doesn't work either. I know I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: See the answer(s) to [How to start bash and immediately “type” command into it?](http://superuser.com/questions/546604/how-to-start-bash-and-immediately-type-command-into-it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, your bash aliases are not available to screen. There's a couple ways to fix this.

- If your aliases are in `.bash_profile`, move them to `.bashrc`
- Start your bash shells with the `-l` switch to force bash to parse `.bash_profile`

Have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/218015/linux-aliases-when-using-screen) for a similar issue.

**EDIT**

There's actually two things that keep this from working:

**Use `bash`'s command-string syntax to pass commands to the new window**

```
    screen -t "YayScreen" bash -c "man screen"
```

**Aliases are a pain in screen**

Create a bash script with the desired name in your $PATH (say, `/bin`), and call that in the same way as the above example. For example, I have a very simple alias called `psgrep` that looks for a process by name. I create this script as `/bin/psgrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $1
```

Then I can add this to my `.screenrc`:

```
screen -t "Useless Command" bash -c "psgrep gnome"
```

See this old [Mac OS X forum post](http://forums.macnn.com/90/mac-os-x/284005/gnu-screen-and-aliases/) for a longer list of what *didn't* work.

Comment: Ok, I tried doing "screen -t qf1 bash -l qf" with no luck. I did see that question already. I think this question is more about the syntax of .screenrc.

Comment: Ah. I didn't read your original question closely enough. Adding another answer now.

Comment: Or just an edit. That works, too.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: My aliases are in `.bashrc` and i still can't use them with screen

Comment: `screen -t cms 4 . ~/.bashrc; edc-cms-local` says permission denied